# Passing in environment variables after upgrade to Laravel MIX 6

Tags: laravel-mix, webpack-5

Before upgrade to Laravel-Mix 6:

- Laravel-Mix version: 5.0.9 (supports Webpack 4)
- NPM version: 6.14.5

With this laravel mix version I was able to pass in environment variables to **webpack.mix.js** by running the npm scripts defined in package.json:

`"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ENV_FILE=./.env.local node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"`

...

`"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production ENV_FILE=./.env.production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"`

Then I could access the variable in webpack.mix.js, whose value depends on whether I was running on production or development mode:

```
let mix = require("laravel-mix");
mix.env(process.env.ENV_FILE);
```

This worked fine!

After upgrade to Laravel-Mix 6:

- Laravel Mix version: 6.0.19 (Webpack 5 supported)
- NPM version: 6.14.5

I followed the recommendations from the laravel [documentation](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/upgrade#update-your-npm-scripts) including the update of the npm scripts...

Following the instructions on the documentation how to pass in environment variables to Webpack CLI (please refer to https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/cli#pass-options-to-webpack-cli), the npm scripts where then changed as follows:

`"dev": "mix -- --env ENV_FILE=./.env.local",`

`"production": "mix --production -- --env ENV_FILE=./.env.production"`

The problem is, that I cannot access the environment variable in **webpack.mix.js** anymore via `process.env.ENV_FILE`. Its value is undefined...

I already checked out in node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js through console.log, that the variable indeed was passed in:

```
const { assertSupportedNodeVersion } = require('../src/Engine');

module.exports = async (config) => {
    assertSupportedNodeVersion();
    
    console.log("ENV_FILE: ", config.ENV_FILE);

    const mix = require('../src/Mix').primary;

    require(mix.paths.mix());

    await mix.installDependencies();
    await mix.init();

    return mix.build();
};
```

And by running for instance `npm run dev` I can see the value logged out:

`mix -- --env ENV_FILE=./.env.local`

`ENV_FILE:  ./.env.local`

So the question is, why I cannot access the environment variable in **webpack.mix.js**, and more importantly, **how** can I do it.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3):

[Laravel Mix 6 / Customize the Mix Configuration Path](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/cli#customize-the-mix-configuration-path)

There is no need to pass settings via env params anymore - simply specify different webpack.mix.js files for each script variation using `--mix-config` option and incorporate any additional settings (statically) into these:

```
"dev": "mix --mix-config=webpack.mix.dev.js",
"production": "mix --mix-config=webpack.mix.prod.js --production"
```

etc. Of course you can then still `require` a common `webpack.mix.js` containing the actual mix logic.